# sed to syntax to include double quotes into last field

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Trying to accomplish below, for a file containing 50,000 chown commands

```
chown eme:curs "GCPB/control_Update_v1 (2).p"
```

The last field does not have `""` in the file, and i need that to ensure command completes correctly.

Any ideas please how to accomplish this?

Comment: not sure what you mean with `The last field does not have "" in the file`. Could you clarify?

Comment: You have a file with lines that say `chown` `user:group` `filename` but the filename may contain spaces/etc. but without proper quoting? And you want to places quotes around the filename? Whatever the filename is?

Comment: @Etan, yes, that is what i'd like to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess you're talking about having a bunch of commands to do on files with spaces in them, hence needing to quote.

Something like this will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#<> reads stdin or files specified on command line, like sed/grep
while ( my $line = <> ) {
    #remove trailing linefeed
    chomp ( $line );
    #split on whitespace - 3 fields limit. 
    my @fields = split ( ' ', $line, 3 );
    #stick them back together again, including quotes. 
    print join ( " ", @fields[0,1], '"'.$fields[2].'"' ),"\n";
}
```

- We split on whitespace, but specify there's only 3 "fields".
- we join together the three fields, and quote the 'third' (field 2, because arrays are zero based in perl).

So with input of:

```
chown eme:curs GCPB/control_Update_v1 (2).p
chown eme:curs some-other file
```

This gives us:

```
chown eme:curs "GCPB/control_Update_v1 (2).p"
chown eme:curs "some-other file"
```

Can be one-linerified if you really want though.

Something like:

```
perl -lne '@f=split(' ', $_, 3); print join (" ", @f[0,1], "\"".$f[2]."\"")'
```

Answer (score 0):

A gawk solution (assuming lines are either unquoted or correctly quoted):

```
awk '/"$/{print;next} {print gensub(/ /, " \"", 2)"\""}' file
```

Comment: this is very close , probably needs little tweaking, the filename field has two double quotes at the beginning, like this

chown eme:curs ""GCPB/control_Update_v1 (2).p"

Comment: Was scrolling through my 50,000 entries list, and it seems its also doing this

chown est:curs ""./Weekly" Meetings/Archive/CM tm mtg 10-8-13"

Comment: Ah, true. I wasn't accounting for correct lines.